# Search Engine that can use SKOS?

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, semantic-web, faceted-search

I am currently working on project where we want to take SKOS and plug it into a search engine to make the search results better.  An example of this would be something like [Semaphore Smartlogic](http://www.smartlogic.com/demonasa.htm) (closed, not free, too big to partner with).

Searchblox is a very good, free, configurable, lucene/solr search engine, but it does not have SKOS abilities and is not open source.

Constellio is similar to Searchblox (not quite as good), and claims to be working on accepting SKOS, but I can't get it to function properly.

Before I go and build this: Does anyone know of an existing free search engine that has has the ability to accept SKOS?  Or, does any know of an open source Lucene/Solr search engine like Searchblox that I could add this functionality to quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You know Solr is a search engine on it's own? Check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ for more info.

A Google search led me to http://code.google.com/p/lucene-skos/wiki/HowTo

Not the most active project, but I guess a good start.

Should't have to be too hard to combine the 2 into the solution you need.

Comment: I am planning to marry solr and skos-lucene if nothing currently exists and use that as a starting place. I read there is a quite a bit of configuration involved in setting up solr.  LucidWorks and Searchblox have done a lot of the heavy lifting with search engine UI, so I was hoping that there was something like them out there that have SKOS abilities, or I could add SKOS to.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if [SIREn](http://siren.sindice.com/index.html) supports SKOS, but it is a semantic lucene plugin that may be worth checking out.

Comment: I'm not sure if it meets the immediate need of directly making use of SKOS, but it looks pretty cool, I'm going to look into it more. Thanks for the help Paige!